# How to trigger REST request in SOAPUI with Groovy script test step

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

With the below script I'm able to send the data/payload to my POST request. However, notable to run the post request from the script.  Need post request in loop.

```
def POSTForgivness = testRunner
   .testCase
   .getTestStepByName("postforgivness")
   .getT‌​estRequest() 
POSTForgivness.setRequestContent(ForgivnessPayload)
```

Other info from comments:

- each time in loop I have different data for post request
- not load testing, but post request with different input data
- have got some 900+ records, able to read and send the data to post request but the post request in not triggering/running after that in the loop.

Comment: //Calling the POST Forgivness API for each record in the JSON File.
def POSTForgivness = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("postforgivness").getTestRequest()
POSTForgivness.setRequestContent(ForgivnessPayload) }

Comment: Would you please edit the question and address these questions? 1. is there any change in the request each time? 2. Are you trying to load test? You may explain your use case a bit  more.

Comment: 1. Yes, each time in loop I have different data for post request

Comment: 2. not load testing, but post request with different input data

Comment: 3. I have some 900+ record, able to read and send the data to post request but the post request in not triggering/running after that in the loop.

Comment: Are you using open source software? or pro?

Comment: Open Source SoapUI  5.3.0

Comment: Thanks for the details. One more, does each `json` request in a separate file? Do you want to send them in a specific order while testing? Do you want to do anything after receiving response?

Comment: one singe json file with multiple json records: no order needed: i'm just checking for success response which i'm good with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155939/discussion-between-rao-and-rajesh-varma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: sudo code

1. get the test step by name
2. set the new request to next step
3. run the step
4. need to disable the rest step as every thing is controlled by step1 (which is groovy script step)

```groovy
//Get the next step
def nextStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("postforgivness")
//Set the new request
nextStep.httpRequest.requestContent = ForgivnessPayload
//run next step
nextStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

Just loop thru the above code until you finish the data

Answer (score 0):

Re Need post request in loop.

This sounds like a data-driven test as opposed to a load test.

Place your post-forgiveness request between a 'Data Source' step and a 'Data Source Loop' step.

You can then 'loop' over your post-forgiveness step as many times as there are rows set up in your data source step.  For each row you have set up, you can define the payload to 'squirt' into your request.

There is an excellent article on the SoapUI website https://www.soapui.org/data-driven-tests/functional-tests.html.

Comment: Thanks Chris:My data source is a json file, I have experience in using data source from MySQL DB but never used data source from json file so I wrote a script for reading the json file.i would like to find a way to trigger the rest request from script

Comment: OK, looking in SoapUI, there are several valid data source inputs, but there isn't one for JSON.  Can you create a spreadsheet such that each row contains the data from one JSON object in your file?  If so, it's really easy to the use that so you can call your tests request for each row int he spreadsheet.